# Type safe React TypeScript HTML select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I’m trying to write a type safe HTML select component in React with TypeScript, but I have some issues in doing so.

I want two things:

- a type safe HTML select component
- use the selected option key as a type constrained value to pass to my backend

I ended up doing something like this:

**select.tsx**

```js
import type { ChangeEvent } from 'react'

type Props<T> = {
  readonly value: T
  readonly options: Array<{ key: T; value: string }>
  readonly onChange: (value: T) => void
}

function Select<T extends string>({ value, options, onChange, ...props }: Props<T>) {
  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const option = options.find((option) => option.key === event.target.value)

    if (option) {
      onChange(option.key)
    }
  }

  return (
    <select {...props} value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
      {options.map((option) => (
        <option key={option.key} value={option.key}>
          {option.value}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  )
}

export default Select
```

**index.tsx**

```js
export const difficulties = [
  { key: 'EASY', value: 'Facile' },
  { key: 'MEDIUM', value: 'Moyen' },
  { key: 'HARD', value: 'Difficile' },
  { key: 'DEMONIC', value: 'Démoniaque' },
] as const

export type Difficulty = (typeof difficulties)[number]['key'] //  "EASY" | "MEDIUM" | "HARD" | "DEMONIC"

/* Some more code */
```

**some-component.tsx**

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import { difficulties, type Difficulty } from './index.tsx'
import Select from './select.tsx'

type Props = {
  initialDifficulty: Difficulty
}

function SomeComponent({ initialDifficulty }: Props) {
  const [difficulty, setDifficulty] = useState(initialDifficulty)

  const updateDifficulty = (updatedDifficulty: Difficulty) => {
    setDifficulty(updatedDifficulty)
    // Call backend here with new difficulty string as EASY, MEDIUM, HARD or DEMONIC
  }

  return (
    <Select
      options={difficulties} // ❌ Error
      value={difficulty} //  "EASY" | "MEDIUM" | "HARD" | "DEMONIC"
      onChange={updateDifficulty} //  (value: "EASY" | "MEDIUM" | "HARD" | "DEMONIC") => void
    />
  )
}
```

My issue is that when using the `Select` component this way, I get the following TypeScript error:

```
The type 'readonly [{ readonly key: "EASY"; readonly value: "Facile"; }, { readonly key: "MEDIUM"; readonly value: "Moyen"; }, { readonly key: "HARD"; readonly value: "Difficile"; }, { readonly key: "DEMONIC"; readonly value: "Démoniaque"; }]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type '{ key: "EASY" | "MEDIUM" | "HARD" | "DEMONIC"; value: string; }[]'.
```

If I remove the `as const` from the `export const difficulties = [/* ... */]`, the error goes away, but then the `Difficulty` type is just `string` so I loose the type safety.

Is there a way to achieve my goal, or am I just overthinking things ?

I should also mention that I’m new to TypeScript, so if this is a dumb question, please forgive me.

Comment: because you define values as const then get the type inferred as readonly array you should also type prop as ` readonly options: ReadonlyArray<{ key: T; value: string }>` rather than array. A readonly array will accept arrays and readonly arrays, then anyway you don't mutate it in code so works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you notice in your question, a const declaration

```
const difficulties = [
  { key: "EASY", value: "Facile" },
  { key: "MEDIUM", value: "Moyen" },
  { key: "HARD", value: "Difficile" },
  { key: "DEMONIC", value: "Démoniaque" },
] as const;
```

is inferred as type

```
readonly [{
    readonly key: "EASY";
    readonly value: "Facile";
}, {
    readonly key: "MEDIUM";
    readonly value: "Moyen";
}, {
    readonly key: "HARD";
    readonly value: "Difficile";
}, {
    readonly key: "DEMONIC";
    readonly value: "Démoniaque";
}]
```

Any indexing on the array type, for example

```
type Difficulty = (typeof difficulties)[number]["key"]
```

just gives you a union so it does not matter if values were from a const or not as unions have no concept of readonly or not, so that works. That's why there's no issue passing value prop.

If you however want to pass the array itself, you need to accommodate for the fact the array is a readonly array. Alternatively you could epxlitly cast the values as a  non readonly array with same members but that's generally not what you want to do for these kind of situations.

When using constants to enumerate possible options it's generally just easier to make arguments accept readonly arrays as you often have no use mutating options, in complex cases where options will change this is generally representable in state as further mappings between types.

So any function that accepts readonly arrays will also accept arrays, take this simple example

```
  type ReadonlyNumbers = readonly number[];
  type Numbers = number[];

  const acceptNumbers = <T extends number[]>(a:T)=>{};

  const acceptReadonlyNumbers = <T extends readonly number[]>(a:T)=>{}

  const numbers = [1,2,3] as Numbers;
  const readonlyNumbers = [1,2,3] as ReadonlyNumbers

  //only accepts non readonly numbers
  acceptNumbers(numbers);
  acceptNumbers(readonlyNumbers);

  //accepts readonly and non readonly arrays
  acceptReadonlyNumbers(numbers);
  acceptReadonlyNumbers(readonlyNumbers)
```

So in your case, simply changing the options prop to accept a readonly array will solve the type issues

```
type Props<T> = {
  readonly value: T;
  readonly options: ReadonlyArray<{ key: T; value: string }>; 
  readonly onChange: (value: T) => void;
};
```

Can check the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBXAZyQGUYUYkBfOAMyghDgCIpUMmBuAKC9EljgwAnmCS44AYQAWKAHYBzJAFEAbklnxqdBs1boYnHsNFwACvTAEAPABUAfHAC8uLnDh6AJhFkAbIXBUUHzwkAC44G243T28-OAgwGGBvAnDkFC9fIQBBKCgUISscOABrJCFwyICgkPCCGChgBThKOyj3VEy472k5RXCACkDgsIiASicHFQhgD25Kbi4aPFkMZNk4YiQfJAxbOCQADwpZDwI4esaFOwGcV2qRzHuEpJSntx6ZBSR3uAA6AFgCwELiUcLmBLWewTO5uNApeBfDw7XrfJxwAZINQacKoxSqdQwKwACRsAFkADJbHYYJQ7ECEuwTRwOWFuODw2T1eKJdbol7rAh-GhNDwDAYC7zMhyS2R-Mr%20RxKg7YmB-MhQRRq4YhMaLdlwYA0DGymH3A2fPpICW87zy8p680te4LHjRJAwPBQDYDJ1WIg0%20A4AF-IGQ6g6pCOHCR6iW77RpEor6KVpOtw4WVCkAoMDi02TDHp9lWWWlcrR2X2oQRmpRzO2uUKtMG1u4Kux4tuKwAelldmLYzGlD9PYDuxgA7cjpHXE53I8RpFaDwPiSSHOzgA2vdigrwkwlNliABNJjYSMHgBi6GAOyYLV%20e-KB7JSgAIgBJACqZPPD1qZgyQgIR1AfSgn3LCpmGJbIEHff9L2Yd8l2ANA7yQcDIP3ZClDJAB5AA5T8JEQusD3fABLkBvGAFAAEcQiwrgAF04BQc55xgRZjDEFCaGXVdhHRAZeIgY1FwEtChOADcxi3WQ8BAAAjJAoBYrcmAVJgWI4OAex7OBAF4NwBJHeYI9TwfAAfICPx-P84BsphYPg6zcII4jSJ4NleLMYF0TZNwmmAJIgn4wS12g8LpMi9pXXuZZVleDZiAYJAJAYSBZEJW5DVkEK6J8aKV0ilpwWBM0DS4uAt0kiLhGwIgYGKoShDY5xCBIMgKAGYLQqK1CSuER0nWqvAwA8cgkBa0rnAGcbJooDwZuEcIVqEaUXDbJr1vmiapuWwbWsdNsDMkIIfDgZT0DKU44CkNSxAAdxCqQ4Gyp64DqmLhMuJp5HY84LJPbA3y-X9sBc994igOB3zwoiSKdeKDVYT1vSLNsrGpCcux5ZKCGjb6htkghqDOwAZcjgJQ8mgPHIyJo7IvJwzTPM48z0c2zwYcpyobcph4Y8kimDx%20NFGjBapvWlnjLMoZyPZyyuaYMH7IF-mVaFxHSM26ZZmLHsp3ZE7nVnLgfJEMR0i6IRCKU1SoE3DoMlifxFJUtSt10%205fPtz2nfRD3He9-UOQRdi0DQJBEn9x3nf2I4TjOd6Ha9libhQUIbDGFkcBR8OuXgdBo8SG23bjtSE5sA5jnUFOYiyVOA%209zPs9zux87dQvuWDqv0S3ABGTAACZMAAZjYji4Erp32mqxu-Fn52h9Hiep-OcusmX7uDLdyPS5gc5ZG8F3beb%20P7hLmOYGXgY%206d03r9jtOnYGRe7dfggRrcAzn6Ps%20%2085AeHeqfD%207E8gFBBG4f%20W8l5f3vl-J%20Ucb5wM-gHAg79OgVyQTwSgQA)

To address more generally the question around whether this is overcomplicating or not I'd say it depends mainly on the structure and relations of the data.

For relatively simple data like flat lists it's usually quite straight forward. It get's complicated if you try preserving exact literal types for complex relations especially if you start doing any kind of mapping on literals then might find it  better to just use primitive likes string or numbers.

If you have strongly typed server client communication and this is of value then can be worth it, if you're going to validate and resolve all types on your server anyway then just using types excepted by html element may be simpler, but also depends on communication between your components. If you have wrapper like `Select` over usual selects then those can mostly handle a lot of the type complexity and the props they take can be easily compatible with rest of types. Either way I think from experience that when it becomes too complex that it's not worth it, its quite noticeable and can just chose to use string, number, boolean.

Comment: Oh my, thank you for this detailed explanation ! Using a ReadonlyArray did the trick, and since this component will mostly (if not only) be used for very simple data, I think the current type complexity is fairly acceptable. Also, I do have strong typing on the server, that is why I needed this kind of type safety in the first place on the front-end. Thanks again !